# ESLint plugin to detect type aliases for primitive types

Tags: typescript, eslint

In a project that my team is working on, we have type aliases for primitive types. The reason, I got from my team, for this is to have consistency across the codebase.

```
type FruitName = string;

const fruits: FruitName[] = ['apple', 'banana']
```

Now, because of this, if I use alias in a function argument, and when I hover on it, my IDE shows that the type is `FruitName`. It gives a feeling that maybe `FruitName` is an object instead of a string.

Is there an ESLint plugin that can help to avoid type aliases for primitive types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@typescript-eslint/no-type-alias` rule like this:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-type-alias': ['error', {
  allowAliases: 'in-unions-and-intersections',
  allowConstructors: 'never',
  allowLiterals: 'always',
  allowGenerics: 'always',
  allowTupleTypes: 'always',
  allowMappedTypes: 'always'
}]
```

See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-type-alias.md